# How can I overwrite the default gateway which radvd is advertising

Tags: ipv6, cloud, dhcp-server, radvd

I have flat network with 7 nodes, one of the nodes act as the DHCPv6 server and also runs radvd.

When used like that, radvd will use the helper node (local-link) IP as the gateway when sending the RA.

How can I manually set/force/overwrite the IP that radvd will send as the network gateway?

Note, I get the IPv6 subnet as is from the cloud provider, I only get static routing, nothing else. I can manually configure each node, and set the GW address manually, but that is not what I'm looking for.

[image: Basic network diagram]

Comment: Is the whole subnet routed to your host, or is it on-link for eth0?

Comment: All the subnet it routed, and all the nodes are this vlan which this subnet is part of.
see the picture in the post.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot; the host that issues the Router Advertisement must be the router itself (unlike DHCP, there is no option to send RAs on behalf of another gateway), and per RFC 4861 section 4.2, Router Advertisements *must* be sent from the link-local address.

If all hosts are directly connected to the upstream network (e.g. through a switch), then you need to place your own router in front of them all which would issue RAs – or the "helper node" needs to be turned into a router for the rest. (The new router will also need to run Proxy-NDP, as the subnet is "on link" for the upstream gateway; fortunately this has zero additional impact on performance, but not all routers support this feature.)

It may be possible to broadcast *fake* RAs via packet injection tools (e.g. using scapy), edited to use the upstream gateway's link-local address as source (instead of your host's), but it must still be a link-local address. If you don't know the gateway's link-local address, sometimes it can be found in a packet capture or derived from the gateway's MAC address.

Comment: What other options do I have if the router won't send RA to advertise itself as the GW?

Comment: If the nodes are VMs on a single host, have the host _become_ the router for the prefix (as opposed to just bridging everything to the main network). If the /64 is routed by the network operator to the host, then it's already in perfect position to be a router; if the /64 is set up as on-link, Proxy-NDP can work around that. If the nodes are all independent (just sharing the same /64), could still do that, though it's less nice.

Comment: What does your current setup look like? i.e. how are the nodes connected to each other and to the cloud provider? The graphic still tells very little.

Comment: Added a picture, to the question

Comment: That's the same picture you already had before; it doesn't clarify much. How are the "nodes" currently configured? *What* are the nodes – VMs or physical hosts? If they're VMs, are they all hosted on your physical host or are they managed by the cloud service?

Comment: All nodes are bare-metal, and I provision them manually via PXE (runs on the helper-node)